# Rasppberry Pi 3 Model B上で動作させるOpenCV を用いたシステムの開発環境について

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, windows-10

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B上で動くOpenCVを用いたシステムの開発を行いたいのですが, 開発環境の設定方法がよくわかりません.
そもそもプログラミングをRaspberry PiとWindows10のどちらでやった方がやりやすいのかもよくわからないので, おすすめの開発環境とその設定方法について教えていただけると幸いです.
よろしくお願いします.

-追記
・ 言語はC++を想定, Linuxは数ヶ月前に初めて触れるのでWindowsの方がまだ慣れていると思います.

Answer (score 0):

「Raspberry Pi 3 Model B上で動くOpenCVを用いたシステムの開発」をするのであれば、Raspberry pi 3の環境(RaspbianなどのLinux系)に触らずに済ませる訳にはいきません。

Raspberry piで動くシステムなら、Raspberry piのメジャーな開発環境で構築するのが素直だと思いますよ。

Comment: 具体的にどんな開発環境がありますか？